# How to measure the time taken by c:import tag

Tags: java, performance, jsp, jstl, monitoring

I was analysing the response time of a website page and sometimes it appears that the page loads really slowly.

The page is in JSTL and uses many `c:import` tag that call URLs from other servers.

I'm trying to understand what is causing these slownesses so I'd like to know if it is possible to measure the time taken by the `c:import` to retrieve the content from the URL.

I've tried that but it's not precise enough I'm not sure I can rely on that :

```
<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date" /> 
<fmt:formatDate type="time" value="${now}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s.SSS"/><br/> {now} 
<c:import url="${url}"/> 
<jsp:useBean id="now2" class="java.util.Date" /> 
<fmt:formatDate type="time" value="${now2}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s.SSS"/><br/> ${now2}
```

Comment: You've tried what exactly?

Comment: @EJP Actually I've tried that `<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date" />
<fmt:formatDate type="time" value="${now}" /><br/>
{now}
<c:import url="${url}"/>
<jsp:useBean id="now2" class="java.util.Date" />
<fmt:formatDate type="time" value="${now2}" /><br/>
${now2}` but it's quite useless...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display the date with a millisecond precision using the `pattern` attribute:

```
<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date" /> 
<fmt:formatDate type="time" value="${now}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s,S" /><br/> {now} 
<c:import url="${url}"/> 
<jsp:useBean id="now2" class="java.util.Date" /> 
<fmt:formatDate type="time" value="${now2}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s,S" /><br/> ${now2}
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry for having forgotten to put the pattern in my question. I already tried that actually. It add precision that's truebut I'm not really sure it's a valid way to measure the c:import time. I put the block of code to illustrate what I've done but I'm looking for something different and proven efficient.